# Remove previous .on() event after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm loading a partial page (in `ASP.NET-MVC`) after an `Ajax` request (`Ajax.BeginForm`).

Within that page, I've some jQuery `.on` handlers, that I cannot move in another place (since it render some @Model properties; i.e. it must stay on that partial page):

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function (e) {
    var myVar = '@Model.MyVar';

    // code
});
```

The problem is: once I reload that partial, and I click on `#test`, its called twice. If I reload again, it's called 3 times, and so on.

Because the handlers is duplicate on each ajax call.
Is there a way to remove previous `.on` (**if any**)? Or to make it **unique**?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simply need to use the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) event:

```
$(document).off("click", "#test");
$(document).on("click", "#test", function (e) {
    var myVar = '@Model.MyVar';

    // code
});
```